# Remove class when selecting different radio button

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble removing a class when checking another radio button in the same group. Right now, the class sticks and never goes away.

```
$(function(){

$('input[name=radio]').change(function(){          
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
              $(this).closest('div').addClass("payBoxSelected");
            } else {
              $(this).closest('div').removeClass("payBoxSelected");
            }                                               
   });

});
```

Any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: Show your html as well

Comment: The change event for a radio fires for the element that is selected, not for the unchecked ones.  It will always be checked.

Comment: Side note for the answers below.  If you have a collection of all the radios, doing $allTheRadios.not(this) will return you all the unselected radios that you could remove the class from.  Since you know it's the selected one, you don't have to do your if logic.  Side-side note, even if you are doing the if `element.checked` is available so you don't have to do $(element).is(':checked')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are only changing (adding or removing) class of the radio that is checked the other radio does not change (hence seems stuck). How about first remove class from all and then add desired class only to the checked radio?

Try this:

```
$('input[name=radio]').change(function(){ 
   //first remove class from all
   $('input[name=radio]').closest('div').removeClass("payBoxSelected");         

   //now add the class to checked radio
   if($(this).is(":checked")){
      $(this).closest('div').addClass("payBoxSelected");
   }                                            
});
```

Comment: Awesome! Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it's a best practice, but this will work:

```
var inputs$ = $('input[name=radio]');
inputs$.change(function () {
    inputs$.each(function (index, el) {
        if ($(el).is(":checked")) {
            $(el).closest('div').addClass("payBoxSelected");
        } else {
            $(el).closest('div').removeClass("payBoxSelected");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type=radio]').click(function () {
        $('input[name='+$(this).attr('name')+']:not(:checked)').removeClass("payBoxSelected");
        $('input[name='+$(this).attr('name')+']:checked').addClass("payBoxSelected");
    });    
});​
```